# JavaCV - Why IplImage.createFrom(image) doesn't exist anymore?

Tags: java, bufferedimage, javacv, iplimage

I'm working with JavaCV at the moment, to try some simple blob detection. I'm using maven and got JavaCV 0.11 (more specific org.bytedeco.javacv) from their repositories. Everything compiles without errors and works fine, but the method to create an IplImage from an BufferedImage seems like it doesn't exist. Eclipse says

```
The method createFrom(BufferedImage) is undefined for the type opencv_core.IplImage
```

I have no idea what the problem is because everything works fine except this one method so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The reason...

JavaCV 0.11 has introduced the concept of `FrameConverter`.

The goal is to don't create unecessary coupling between an application using JavaCV and another API (FFmpeg, Java 2D...).

Instead, JavaCV uses [`Frame`](http://bytedeco.org/javacv/apidocs/org/bytedeco/javacv/Frame.html) class instances for storing audio samples or video image data. Those frames can be later  shared between various APIs thanks to [`FrameConverter`](http://bytedeco.org/javacv/apidocs/org/bytedeco/javacv/FrameConverter.html)s.

See more: [JavaCV Frame Converters](http://bytedeco.org/news/2015/04/04/javacv-frame-converters/)

#### The workaround...

It's always possible copy and paste the code of the `createFrom` method into your own code or refactor it using `FrameConverter`s.

Below is the (not compiled) code of the method taken from the source repository:

```
public static IplImage createFrom(BufferedImage image) {
    return createFrom(image, 1.0);
}

public static IplImage createFrom(BufferedImage image, double gamma) {
    return createFrom(image, gamma, false);
}

public static IplImage createFrom(BufferedImage image, double gamma, boolean flipChannels) {
    if (image == null) {
        return null;
    }
    SampleModel sm = image.getSampleModel();
    int depth = 0, numChannels = sm.getNumBands();
    switch (image.getType()) {
        case BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB:
        case BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB:
        case BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB_PRE:
        case BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_BGR:
            depth = IPL_DEPTH_8U;
            numChannels = 4;
            break;
    }
    if (depth == 0 || numChannels == 0) {
        switch (sm.getDataType()) {
            case DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE:   depth = IPL_DEPTH_8U;  break;
            case DataBuffer.TYPE_USHORT: depth = IPL_DEPTH_16U; break;
            case DataBuffer.TYPE_SHORT:  depth = IPL_DEPTH_16S; break;
            case DataBuffer.TYPE_INT:    depth = IPL_DEPTH_32S; break;
            case DataBuffer.TYPE_FLOAT:  depth = IPL_DEPTH_32F; break;
            case DataBuffer.TYPE_DOUBLE: depth = IPL_DEPTH_64F; break;
            default: assert false;
        }
    }
    IplImage i = create(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), depth, numChannels);
    i.copyFrom(image, gamma, flipChannels);
    return i;
}
```

Reference: [opencv_core.java](https://code.google.com/r/lh44166-javacv-example/source/browse/src/main/java/com/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core.java?r=9589630c2cbc00b3f48714c3adf1da72d28f274a)

Comment: The copyFrom() method in IplImage does not exist.